# Save plot.ly JSON to a file

Tags: python, json, plotly

I need to save the JSON code that generates a plot.ly chart to a .json file to be used elsewhere, and I need to do this with multiple charts. Is there a nice way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried the builtin `json.dump()` function from the `json` package? More [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `fig.to_json()` or `fig.write_json()`.